# Why is the following surface integral wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

Calculate $
\int \int_Sf(x,y,z)dS$

For part of the surface $x=z^3$, where $0\leq x,y \leq 14^{-\frac{3}{2}}$; $f(x,y,z) =x$

The parametrization of the surface seems simple enough:

$s(u,v) = \langle u^3,v,u \rangle$

Thus we compute the normal to the surface:

$s_u = \langle 3u^2,0,1\rangle$; $s_v = \langle 0,1,0 \rangle$

The jacobian yields:

$s_u \times s_v = \langle 1,0,3u^2\rangle$

$|s_u \times s_v| = \sqrt{9u^4+1}$

Ans thus:

$\int \int_Sf(x,y,z)dS = \int \int_Df(s(u,v))\|\vec n\|dA = \int^{14^{-3/2}}_0 \int^{14^{-3/2}}_0 u^3\sqrt{9u^4+1}$ $dudv$

Which according to Wolfram is $\approx 6.338403326748645^{-10}$

This is wrong, and I am not sure why it is wrong.

Comment: what a weird bound $14^{-3/2}$. what is your result to say that it is wrong ? Did you integrate it?

Comment: I put it into the software that is asking me for the answer and it said it was wrong

Comment: Hmm I got the integral equals 0.25x14^(-6), which is 3x10^(-8).  It's integrable by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ represents $z$ and $x=z^3=u^3$,

If $0 \leq x \leq 14^{-\frac32}$, we should have

$$0 \leq u \leq 14^{-\frac12}.$$

Comment: thank you, I completely missed that.